# "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED"

Tags: c++

Alguém pode me ajudar aqui? problema no destrutor.

(UP) acho que encontrei o problema, vou comentar no código:

Se alguém poder me dar algumas dicas sobre boas praticas nesse código, por favor!

```
Kript::Kript(const char* novoTexto)
{
    texto_size = strlen(novoTexto); // * essa linha mudei para (strlen(novoTexto)+1)*
    texto = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*texto_size);
    strcpy(texto, novoTexto);       // *pois aqui strcpy copia novoTexto + '\0'*
    kripted_txt = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*texto_size);
    Enkrip();
}



void Kript::Enkrip()
{
    file = fopen("KRIPTED.txt", "w");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "ERRO AO ABRIR ARQUIVO";
    }
    else
    {
        int* EOF_POINT = kripted_txt;
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < texto_size; i++, j = 0)
        {
            if (j > KEY_SIZE)
                j = 0;
            kripted_txt[i] = texto[i] * key[j];
            EOF_POINT++;
        }
         EOF_POINT--;      //<- adicionado, pois EOF estava sendo adicionado...
                           //...Fora do espaco alocado

        *EOF_POINT = EOF;  // agora sim
        EOF_POINT = kripted_txt;

        while (*EOF_POINT != EOF)
        {
            fprintf(file, "%d", *EOF_POINT);
            EOF_POINT++;
            if (*EOF_POINT != EOF)
                fprintf(file, " ");

        }



    }

}

Kript::~Kript()
{
   free(texto);   
   free(kripted_txt); 
   fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: O teu código é C++ mas contudo usas malloc and char*? Porque não usar streams e strings para resolver o problema?

Comment: Tens razão, alias já mudei de malloc e free, para new e delete, porem ainda não pratiquei o uso de std::string,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu código tem poucos elementos de c++ ele esta praticamente usando somente o c. Você deve tentar substituir o uso do arrays pelo std::string e também usar a classe para manipulação de arquivos do header fstream. Isso já vai deixar seus código mais claro e com uma menor chance de erros.

Um modificação que já ajudaria um pouco, por exemplo, séria mudar o construtor para o seguinte

```
#include<string>

Kript::Kript(const std::string & novoTexto)
     :texto(novoTexto)
{
      Enkrip();
}
```

Usando o std::string você não vai ficar precisando, a todo tempo, se preocupar com a alocação de memoria e também não precisara ficar guardando o tamanho do string, pois o std::string sabe seu proprio tamanho pelo metodo size() . Da uma olhada na [referencia](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/) do c/c++ provavelmente você consegui fazer as modificações e o problema do seu código desaparecera.